# How do I find Facebook information about a company by using their domain address?

Tags: php, facebook, api, dns, facebook-opengraph

I am writing a program in PHP that requests a domain name from the user, and from this the user will be displayed with social networking information (likes, shares, comments etc) about the domain.

I have tried using several techniques, including;

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?id=www.ebay.co.uk"
```

Although this has a response, it seems to have given me Facebook information regarding the a singular page (home page), instead of the entire site.

Is there a way for me to find the Facebook page of a company when I only have their domain name available?

Any time would be appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Open Graph Protocol is not hierarchical, but a flat structure.
Each page with an og: tag is treated as a completely distinct element.

> Is there a way for me to find the Facebook page of a company when I only have their domain name available?

You can use the og:site_name tag if it's available on the website.
Take tutsplus.com as an example, they have the og:site_name tag with "tuts+" as the value. When searching facebook for a fanpage with the name "Tuts+" you will find facebook.com/tutsplus as the first result.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What would the URL request look like using this method?

Comment: There is no way to ask the facebook API for all Open Graph fields.
You have to call the website in question and read their og:* head tags yourself.